# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

Pardon me for not being clear, but have thia script that is really long. When I have it live, I get this error in Chrome's Console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

here is the snippet of code where it is reading from.

```
var formIddd = $('select[class~="FormField"]').get(numSelec).name.substr($('select[class~="FormField"]').get(numSelec).name.length-3,2);
```

I looked up substr on google and it appears to be a known property. I also found the classes. I have played with the lengths, but still getting stuck. It used to work until BigCommerce did an update.

Any advice much appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Read the error carefully. "Cannot read property 'substr' OF undefined". That means `name` is undefined, not `substr`.

Comment: debug: `var elems = $('select[class~="FormField"]'); console.log(numSelec, elems.length, elems.get(numSelec));`

Comment: @AmitJoki If the index was out of bounds, that would mean the result of `get(numSelec) would be `undefined`, which would result in the error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. So `get(numSelec)` returns something, but it doesn't have a `name` property.

Comment: @forgivenson yup. You're right

Comment: Thank you @epascarello here is the results

    undefined 4 [select#FormField_11.Field200.FormField.field-xlarge, select#FormField_12.FormField.JSHidden.Field200.field-xlarge, select#FormField_21.Field200.FormField.field-xlarge, select#FormField_22.FormField.JSHidden.Field200.field-xlarge]0: select#FormField_11.Field200.FormField.field-xlarge1: select#FormField_12.FormField.JSHidden.Field200.field-xlarge2: select#FormField_21.Field200.FormField.field-xlarge3: select#FormField_22.FormField.JSHidden.Field200.field-xlargelength: 4__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: And there is your problem: `numSelec` is `undefined`.

Comment: @AmitJoki i define the var of numSelec with this line **var numSelec = arrayOfSelectOfCountry[arrayOfSelectOfCountry.length-1];**

Comment: @epascarello meant above for you, but edited it twice already. then arrayOfSelectOCountry is defined too    var arrayOfSelectOfCountry = [];

Comment: You need to show more code, there is something wrong in the execution order.

Comment: @epascarello http://pastebin.com/PRhVt7WR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not populating your array. The if check is false.

[image]

so basically you are doing this

```
var arrayOfSelectOfCountry = [];
var numSelec = arrayOfSelectOfCountry[-1];  //undefined
```

which results in the error above.

Answer (score 0):

maybe at some point the `substr()` is called on a **`null reference`**

so before using it check that reference for nullity  like that

```
function(jsonDate) {

     if (jsonDate!=null) {
        //if the variable is not null you can use substr with no problems
         var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        //.....
}
```

take look at my full snippet from `Datatable`

```
 columns: [
                        { 'data': 'ID' },
                        { 'data': 'Name' },
                        {
                            'data': 'DateCreated',
                            'render': function(jsonDate) {
                                if (jsonDate!=null) {
                                    var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                                    return date.toLocaleDateString();
                                }
                                return "-";
                            }
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
variable.substring(0, 7)
```

Do:

```
variable && variable.substring(0, 7)
```

This is how you check for nullity like Basheer mentioned